# Is the word structure of 'politico-chicanery' acceptable?

Tags: derivational-morphology, word-formation, compound-words

Consider the word combination in the following sentence - “Filmography recapitulating ***politico-chicanery***, the age of the superhero is about to yield to the age of the monster”.

I’ve always thought the prefix ‘politico-‘ is normally followed by another adjective. So, what’s the meaning and purpose of this word form? Is it correct at all?

Here’s the original source - https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2018/02/12/the-strange-and-twisted-life-of-frankenstein

Comment: The *New Yorker*'s use of English is often rather esoteric.

Comment: What would be the difference between "politico-chicanery" and "political chicanery"?  (This is not a question for Мария Волкова except perhaps rhetorically as an expression of support, though I would welcome the opportunity to ask it non-rhetorically of the article's author.  It might also be a useful addition to the present question.)

Comment: Without consulting the original, the use of the word “filmography” seems strange to me (I thought it was a list of films someone had directed or acted in). This makes it difficult for me to understand how a filmography can recapitulate anything of this sort. Perhaps the New Yorker could try plain English occasionally.

Answer (score 3):

The combining form "*politico-*" is used to form both nouns and adjectives, although it seems the majority of the words produced are adjectives.

> (**SOED**) **politico-** *comb. form*. [f. Gk *politicos* (see POLITIC a. & n.) + -o-] Forming ns. and adjs. w. the senses 'politically' as *politico-aesthetic,  politico-ethical*, etc., or 'political and', as *politico-legal, politico-philosophical*, etc.
> **politico-economic** *a;* = POLITICO-ECONOMICAL. **politico-economical** *a.* pertaining or relating to political economy. **politico-religious** *a.*  at once political and religious; *spec.* pertaining to religion as influenced by politics.

It is certain that this is a noun, but it is not as certain which of the two interpretations to choose; is it "politically a chicanery" or "chicanery influenced by politics"? It seems that, as what is being mentioned is "The Bride of Frankenstein" the politics is that refering to woman's emancipation, and, therefore it would be question of "chicanery influenced by politics"; the chicanery would be the invention of a bride for  Frankenstein who is known to have had none in Shelley's book;  these facts make the present point of view probable enough.

Comment: From context in 2018, and being the New Yorker, it most likely refers to Trump (monster) replacing Obama (superhero), the former certainly bringing chicanery in the political sphere (which is presumably the meaning). But that doesn't explain why it uses the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

The number of compounds formed using the prefix *politico-* is not large in any case. [YourDictionary](https://www.yourdictionary.com/politico-economic) lists only

> - *politico-administrative*
> - *politico-economic*
> - *politicoethical*
> - *politicohistorical*
> - *politicoreligious*

All these are compound adjectives, but that is probably because the adjectives are the most useful forms. Why not stick with say the well-established 'political history' for the compound noun? There seems, however, no reason to proscribe nounal forms totally; examples of  reasonable usages found on the internet include

> - *The politico-economics of electricity planning in developing countries*

[[Yakubu Abdul-Salam; Science Direct; Volume 88, January 2016, Pages 299-309](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0301421515301646)]

and

> - *Content was studied from several scientific databases related to CSE in Lebanon from a historical, socioeconomic background, and
>   politico-legalities in Lebanon.*

[[Nazih Raychouni, Independent, 2022; SSRN](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4342664)]

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_terms_prefixed_with_politico-) adds other compounds with the prefix *politico*-:

> *politicocommercial / politicogeographical / politicojudicial / politicolegal / politicomania / politicophilosophical / politicophobia
> / politicospeak / / sociopoliticolegal*

Note that three of the above are nouns.

[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/politico) adds *politico-military* (hyphenation is variable in some cases).

Of course, such morphological patterning does not guarantee that one can use such any similarly derived form at will. Word formation is not unqualifiedly productive. If one cannot find a candidate in a respectable dictionary, or in respectable articles in journals say, it is probably best to avoid or at least add a definition and/or scare quotes in articles in formal registers. Note that most of the examples relate to overlapping fields of study and are serious in register; 'politico-chicanery' smacks of a tongue-in-cheek nonce usage.

Comment: Yes. But 'politico-speak' would surely be taken in a default sense 'what you'd expect the typical politician to say', making the precise derivation academic.

Comment: We can't say from the form whether those are the combinative form coupled with a noun, or a form that uses the noun **politico**

Comment: No, but OP is asking about the acceptability of [politico] + [noun] compounds as opposed to [politico] + [adjective] compounds.

Comment: I understand that. Wiktionary offers no citations to back up the existence of those words (-mania, -phobia, -speak),and if they do indeed have some currency, one would have to check the contexts to see if "politico" means politician or politics. There's a difference.

Answer (score 0):

*Politico-* as a prefix to an adjective can mean *politically* (e.g. *politico-aesthetic*) or *political and [adjective]* (e.g. *politico-literary*).

*Politico-* can also combine with a noun. From the *OED*:

> **politico-** *combining form*
> **2.** As a prefix to a noun (chiefly used *attributive*), as **politico-abolition**, **politico-crime**, **politico-economy**, **politico-travel**, etc.
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Here are a couple of attested usages shown:

> <sub>**1861**   Had it not been for the politico-abolition
> conspirators of this country..this rebellion would never have taken
> place. —*New York Herald* 2 December</sub>
>  <sub>**1998**   In
> place of the defeated amateur, do we not see around us the zeitgeist
> of the politico-philistine? —*Guardian* (Nexis) 10 September 18</sub>

In front of a noun, *politico-* must mean *political*—not *politically*. (Though note that *politico* is also a standalone noun meaning *politician*, and thus could end up as in: *He’s a model-actor; she’s a politico-economist.*)

What’s different about your example is that *chicanery*, unlike *philistine* or *economist*, is an abstract noun.

Is that acceptable? I suppose if you can also brook *The New Yorker*’s diaeresisized *coöperation*, it’s fine.